# how to add a new field in Laravel voyager registration page

Tags: mysql, laravel, voyager

How to add extra field or customize the registration form of voyager admin panel and how to know the password encrypted function for password field in MySQL Database.

**Password encrypted function :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First go to admin panel `Tools->database`. Click `edit bread`. Right side of the screen there is an text area. Write your own customize settings here and save.

If you want add extra field `tools->database` again. This time click edit(right side) and add column. 
If you want to customize the view with extras (not database values) 
copy that file `resources\views\vendor\voyager\bread\browse.php` 
and make folder inside `resources\views\vendor\voyager\users`

After that make `browse.php` and paste. Now this page is viewing in admin screen.

**Answer:**
that column related password field. Right side there is an area. That area for customizing. Like migration tables. When you create migration it comes

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');
```

if you want customize you can put `->` and make your own request. 
In voyager you actually you are putting `->unique()` think like that. For example

```
{
"validation": {
    "rule": "required|max:140"
}
```

}

I write that for body area. If you write hash, bcrypt or smt for password. It will work.

Comment: Ozen.....okay got it.... but what is the 2nd one answer "how to know the password encrypted function for password field in MySQL Database."